# Symbiosis of Pseudomonas Fluorescens

Tags: botany, microbiology

Have a modest background in molecular biology and presently considering a project that requires some knowledge of botany.  Specifically, I seek details on the epiphytic relation between the microbe *pseudomonas fluorescens* and flowering plants such as the orchid and rose.

```
    * What would be the relationship?  Commensalism or Mutualism?
    * What is the nutrient source for Pseudomas? Life Span?
    * What becomes of the metabolic end products from Pseudomonas?
    * Does the plant alter its surface properties to accommodate Pseudomonas?
```